# hover on div in Ionic

Tags: css, ionic-framework, ionic-view

I'm creating an app in ionic and I have two pics on the home site. The background images have a grey filter on it. I want that on hover when user tab to change the opacity from 0.7 to 0.4. But the code :hover in Css does not work. Here are my code snippets

```
        <a class="col-50 div2"  ui-sref="belege">
            <div class="opaq-bg"></div>
            <span>Belege</span>
        </a>
```

and here the css file

```
#home  .div1{
    background-image: url(../img/checkliste.jpg);
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#home  .div2{
    background-image: url(../img/belege.jpg);
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.opaq-bg {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgba(68, 68, 68, 0.7);
    z-index: 0;
}

.opaq-bg:hover {
    background-color: rgba(68, 68, 68, 0.4);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I tested your code and it worked. When I hover on the div, it change it's opacity from 0.7 to 0.4. That's what are you trying to do?

Test only the code you put in your question separately to see the result and then try to search if another code can be making conflict with this one.